# PowerShell won't rename an export .csv file

Tags: powershell, rename

I am trying to rename the file `export.csv` to the `$name` but with a `.csv` extension instead of `.file`. The output is still `$name.file`.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$name = Read-Host "Enter Group Name"
Get-ADGroupMember -identity "$name" -Recursive |select name, SamAccountName| export-csv -path C:\export.csv -NoTypeInformation

get-childItem *.file | Rename-Item -newname {$name.name -replace '\.file', '.csv'}
```

So I did this and it works:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$name = Read-Host "Enter Group Name"
Get-ADGroupMember -identity "$name" -Recursive |select name, SamAccountName| export-csv -path h:\groups\export.csv -NoTypeInformation
rename-item "h:\groups\export.csv" $name
Dir h:\groups\ | Rename-Item -newname {$_.name + '.csv'}
```

But how do I get it to rename the file as I run the command instead of doing it for the whole directory every time? What keeps adding `.csv`?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No it runs and exports the file and adds the .csv to the end but it dows it for the whole folder so when i start doing multiple groups i get file names like group3-name.csv, group2-name.csv.csv, group1name-.csv.csv.csv

Comment: Do you mean (export-csv -path "h:\groups\$Name.csv" -NoTypeInformation) ?

Comment: Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$name = Read-Host "Enter Group Name"
Get-ADGroupMember -identity "$name" -Recursive |select name, SamAccountName| export-csv -path h:\groups\$Name.csv -NoTypeInformation

this worked

Comment: Thank you I thought i had tried that, but I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change this line:
export-csv -path h:\groups\export.csv -NoTypeInformation
to this:
export-csv -path "h:\groups\$Name.csv" -NoTypeInformation